# Selenium IDE 1.9.1 xpath with contains selection

Tags: web-applications, xpath, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use a software name Selenium (web rat) to simulate user interact with browser

For example , I trying to put the username field with name 'john

However the 'id' of 'username textbox' is  username_947232, username_8237

The format which username_[random numbers]

My syntax is following:

```
//*[contains(@id="username_(/\d+/)")]
```

but it's not working , anyone have any idea??

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'username_')
  and 
   floor(substring-after(@id, 'username_')) = substring-after(@id, 'username_')
    ]
```

**Explanation**:

This expression selects any element the string value of whose `id` attribute starts with the string `"username_"` and the remainder of this string (after the starting `"username_"`) is an integer.

Here we use the fact that the following expression is true if and only if `$string` represents an integer:

```
floor($string) = $string
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "//*[starts-with(@id, 'username_')
  and
   floor(substring-after(@id, 'username_')) = substring-after(@id, 'username_')
    ]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
 <user id="username_Xyz"/>
 <user id="username_Xyz123"/>
 <user id="username_123Xyz"/>
 <user id="username_123Xyz456"/>
 <user id="username_2015"/>
</t>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the selected node from this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<user id="username_2015"/>
```

**Do note**: The other two answers to this question would select all 5 `user` elements from the above document -- which, of course, is incorrect.

Comment: +1, interesting way. Though I guess it does depend on his required level of complexity.

Comment: @Arran, you are welcome. The XPath expression in this answer works correctly on any XML document with any level of complexity. The expression `floor($string) = $string` is `true()` exactly when `$string` is a string representation of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `starts-with`

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "username_")]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just use

```
//*[contains(@id, 'username_')]
```

Though this may not be optimal if you have the possibility of anything other than numbers at the end.